# How to set Android toolbar height?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-toolbar

I want to achieve this:

[image]

What I thought was to make a Custom Toolbar with a bigger height and work with the tabhost and tabpager normally. I have implemented it, but the toolbar is showing the normal height, so it doesn't show as I want, just the top part. Is this the right approach or is it possible to set a TabHost below a Linear/Relative Layout? Because I don't need to work with it as an action bar.

**Relevant Code**

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_home"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_version"
        android:text="@string/app_version"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And this function in the Activity:

```
private void setupActionBar()
    {
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_title, null);
        ab.setCustomView(v);
    }
```

Comment: You are using the `ActionBar`. Where is your `Toolbar` code? You can set the height here `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` in your XML. Use height and not minHeight.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/black"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" //pay attention here
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> //pay attention here
```

your `ToolBar` which is a `ViewGroup` is wraping its height around its children meaning it will get a fixed size only if the children are measured. your minimum height is around `50` to `60` `dip`, that is how low your `ToolBar` will be.
so if your children height do not add up to a reasonable big number it will still be `<= 50`

give it a prefered height `android:layout_height="200dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Use some theme with no action bar for this activity or the whole app if you don't need action bar's functionality (like `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar`).
You can add layout of your top bar directly in activities root layout. If you will use it in other activities then consider making separate xml files for layout or even your own ActionBarView class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AppBarLayout like this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:tabBackground="@color/White"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/OrangeFFC200"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```