# How can I change the ActionBar size?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to set the ActionBar size to 80dp. I'm trying this but isn't working:

```
<style name="LargeActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/LargeActionBar.Large</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/LargeActionBar.Large</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LargeActionBar.Large" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:height">80dp</item>
        <item name="height">80dp</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">80dp</item>
    </style>
```

Activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        setTheme(R.style.LargeActionBar);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_actionbar,null);

        actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

I've tried it in two different ways, using `setTheme` and`LayoutInflater`. Is it possible that one is interfering in the other?

Comment: Why is  your "parent"  themes using the "child" themes?

Comment: I tried to create an ActionBar style... Now I can see that is a little stranged. If I do only `<item name="actionBarSize">80dp</item>``on my theme will work?

Comment: You should use a custom Toolbar instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082816/how-to-set-android-toolbar-height

Comment: best explained here http://code2care.org/pages/change-height-of-android-actionbar/